# Ideal camera position For OctoEverywhere's Gadget AI

Tags: octoprint, octopi, camera

I'm trying out [OctoEverywhere's Gadget](https://octoeverywhere.com/gadget) AI print failure detection.

It's been working surprisingly well, but I wondered if there was an ideal camera position, image format, or whatever to ensure it could always catch failures. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal camera position details for AI failure detection are listed on the [Gagdget website](https://octoeverywhere.com/gadget).

But in general, they are:

1. Make sure there's good lighting on the print.
2. Make sure the entire print can be seen at all times, even if the bed moves.
3. Reduce the number of other objects the camera can see to prevent false positive detection.